# How to warn if a text field is empty in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, ios10, guard, calculation

I'm extremely new to Swift 3 and have just been working through a few tutorials picking a few things up along the way. I'm trying to write some code to carry out a calculation based on six different inputs. It works fine but when I leave a text field empty, the app crashes in the Simulator.

I've done loads and loads of searching for an answer and it seems the "let" or "guard let" function is the way to go but I can't seem to successfully implement it. Can anyone help me specifically implement a function that allows me to check if a text field is empty and create a warning or error message?

Here's my code so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var field1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field4: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field5: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field6: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var labelResult: UILabel!

@IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let p = Double (field1.text!)
    let d = Double (field2.text!)
    let s = Double (field3.text!)
    let e = Double (field4.text!)
    let w = Double (field5.text!)
    let y = Double (field6.text!)


    let sum = ((p!*d!)/((2*((s!*e!*w!)+(p!*y!)))))

    labelResult.text = "\(sum)"

    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Sorry if my terminology is incorrect... like I said, I'm extremely new to Swift 3 and any form of coding!!

Thanks in advance.

Rally3

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    guard field1.text.isEmpty else { print("You can print here to notify problem") return }
    guard field2.text.isEmpty else { return }
    etc..
```

That way, you will exit the function soon, so you will not make any calculation with empty values.

Comment: Should guard come before labelResult.text = "\(sum)" ? I can't seem to successfully implement this still!

Comment: you should guard at the beginning, should be the first thing on your function.